# How to calculate a Mod b in Casio fx-991ES calculator

Tags: calculator

Does anyone know how to calculate a Mod b in Casio fx-991ES Calculator. Thanks

Comment: You should really use the Google machine. Look here: http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=38469

Comment: +1 for asking a casio calculator related question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: @bummi shouldn't we move it to math.stackexchange then?

Comment: I found this youtube video and this could be useful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzCOUQMSr8E

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined by the [help].

Comment: @bummi nice to see you here. my delphi friend.

Answer (score 164):

This calculator does not have any modulo function. However there is quite simple way how to compute modulo using display mode `ab/c` (instead of traditional `d/c`).

How to switch display mode to `ab/c`:

- Go to settings (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mode</kbd>).
- Press arrow down (to view more settings).
- Select `ab/c` (number 1).

Now do your calculation (in comp mode), like `50 / 3` and you will see `16 2/3`, thus, mod is `2`. Or try `54 / 7` which is `7 5/7` (mod is `5`).
If you don't see any fraction then the mod is `0` like `50 / 5 = 10` (mod is `0`).

The remainder fraction is shown in **reduced form**, so `60 / 8` will result in `7 1/2`. Remainder is `1/2` which is `4/8` so mod is `4`.

EDIT:
As @lawal correctly pointed out, this method is a little bit **tricky for negative numbers** because the sign of the result would be negative.

For example `-121 / 26 = -4 17/26`, thus, mod is `-17` which is `+9` in mod 26. Alternatively you can add the modulo base to the computation for negative numbers: `-121 / 26 + 26 = 21 9/26` (mod is `9`).

EDIT2: As @simpatico pointed out, this method will not work for numbers that are out of calculator's precision. If you want to compute say `200^5 mod 391` then some tricks from algebra are needed. For example, using rule
`(A * B) mod C = ((A mod C) * B) mod C` we can write:

`200^5 mod 391 = (200^3 * 200^2) mod 391 = ((200^3 mod 391) * 200^2) mod 391 = 98`

Comment: @simpatico because 200^5 is out of range of calc's precision you need to use some tricks from algebra. For example: 200^5 mod 391 = (200^3 mod 391) * 200^2 mod 391 = 98 (you can use mod at 'any time' during computation).

Comment: This result will be inaccurate for negative numbers. For example: -121 mod 26 =  9 because -121 = -5*26 + 9. But 121 mod 26 = 17 because 121 = 4*26+17.

Comment: What about in case of decimal numbers. Like -1/2 mod 23?
William Stalling (Network Security and Cryptography) says its 11 but I don't understand how.

Comment: @Sohaib I guess it depends on your definition of modulo operation. I can imagine very simple extension of modulo operation to real numbers that is defined in the similar fashion as reminder after integer division. In that case `3.14159 mod 1.4` would be `0.34159` (`3.14159 = 2 * 1.4 + 0.34159`). In the same way you can say that if reminder is negative you would turn it to positive so your example `-0.5 mod 23` would be `22.5` in my book. But again, some applications might define modulo in different way.

Comment: @NightElfik Its the computer science modulus division where the remainder is the answer. I also believed 22.5 to be the answer bu apparently 11 is the correct answer.

Comment: @lawal You are right but it is trivial to find any positive integer y that is congruent to some negative integer x (mod n).  Also, any `mod` function will correctly process a negative value.

Comment: Also, the denominator must be the same as the original fraction, else the value in the numerator won't be the correct modulo.

Comment: as @powersource97 correctly pointed out, the resulting denominator should be equal. Take f.e. `288 mod 21`; the result will be displayed as `13 5/7`. As you can see, the denominator is different from 21; so, you have to multiply the numerator by `21/7 = 3`. The answer is then `5 x 3 = 15`.

Comment: Wrong, this calculator has already modulo function: Alpha + fraction

Answer (score 54):

As far as I know, that calculator does not offer mod functions.
You can however computer it by hand in a fairly straightforward manner.
Ex.

(1)50 mod 3

(2)50/3 = 16.66666667

(3)16.66666667 - 16 = 0.66666667

(4)0.66666667 * 3 = 2

Therefore 50 mod 3 = 2

Things to Note:
On line 3, we got the "minus 16" by looking at the result from line (2) and ignoring everything after the decimal. The 3 in line (4) is the same 3 from line (1).

Hope that Helped.

Edit 
As a result of some trials you may get x.99991 which you will then round up to the number x+1.

Comment: And how do I convert decimal to binary conversations by calculator if I don't have the bases mechanism in my calculator?

Comment: Can I find the modulus of a negative by following the above steps ? For Example -151 mod 26

Comment: @Faizan this is a separate question/problem, try asking a question of your own (if it doesn't already exist). But the easiest method I find is to convert it to hexadecimal which then converts to binary instantly (i.e. Dec 10 = Hex A = Binary 1010). There are relatively simple methodologies to go between even very very big (or very very small!) exponential decimal values to hex, google 'em. I had to use them in one of my first year CS exam questions. If you ever need to check the binary of anything, always work in hex rather than decimal anyway.

Comment: @RohitKiran If you add (rather than subtract) n multiples of 26 to -151 until you get a positive value x s.t. 0 ≤ x < 26, then you will see that -151 ≡ x (mod 26).
Or, to put it another way, just use -26 instead and then follow from step (2).
Which, by the way, is too slow and therefore impractical. But it's still worth knowing.

Comment: But in this case, if a fractional value is very large then iun result it will be round off and you could not get correct result

Answer (score 26):

You need **10 ÷R 3 = 1**
This will display both the reminder and the quoitent

---

### ÷R

[image]

Comment: Which model is that exactly? On mine Casio fx-991ES PLUS there's no this R button:(

Comment: Just be careful, while the displayed remainder is correct for a single division, in larger expressions the operator will NOT act as a modulo operator. From the manual: If a ÷R calculation is part of a multi-step calculation, only the quotient is passed on to the next operation. eg. (2÷R3 + 3÷R3) = 1, however (2mod3 + 3mod3) = 2

Comment: I think this is Casio fx-115ES PLUS.

Comment: thanks, it works perfect, you should be higher. I have a fx-991sp x II and it works perfect. Just what i was looking for.

Comment: Other calculators might still have this button in a different location; I have the fx-300es plus and it is [shift]+[Abs] for me instead of [alpha]+[fraction] button shown here

Comment: perfect on fx-375es

Answer (score 15):

There is a switch <kbd>a^b/c</kbd>

If you want to calculate

```
491 mod 12
```

then enter 491 press <kbd>a^b/c</kbd> then enter 12. Then you will get 40, 11, 12. Here the middle one will be the answer that is 11.

Similarly if you want to calculate `41 mod 12` then find 41 <kbd>a^b/c</kbd> 12. You will get 3, 5, 12 and the answer is 5 (the middle one). The `mod` is always the middle value.

Comment: why its not useful? its not the straight method.. but we can find te answer

Comment: I did not downvote, but your answer uses exactly the same methodology as the top voted one (and you wrote it 4 months later). Also, it is very badly explained.

Comment: @Jerry Actually, some calculators (Casio) have a straight `a^b/c` button and don't even have any of the functionality corresponding to the top answer, which I assume is for TI calculators. I have been scouring the internet for a straightforward explanation of how to use `a^b/c` to calculate remainders of integer division on my Casio fx-9750GA PLUS and this was incredibly straightforward after Ajoy's edit.

Comment: I should note however, that even though this saves time, it is still incompatible with large values (i.e. 10 digits +)

Comment: 45 `a^b/c` 6 gives middle value 1. whereas the actual modulus is 3 how come ?

Comment: This is only true if `a mod b` gives output `d^e/b`, otherwise, some multiplications will be needed.

Answer (score 11):

You can calculate **A mod B** (for positive numbers) using this:

**Pol( -Rec( <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2π<sup>r</sup></sub> , 2π<sup>r</sup> × <sup>A</sup>/<sub>B</sub> ) , Y ) ( π<sup>r</sup> - Y ) B**

Then press **[CALC]**, and enter your values for **A** and **B**, and any value for **Y**.

**/** indicates using the fraction key, and **<sup>r</sup>** means *radians* ( **[SHIFT] [Ans] [2]** )

Comment: Function's too complex I can't even type it correctly! Anyway what's that superscripted minus thing between Pol and Rec??

Comment: oh it's just a minus! Why the superscript??

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I usually do it.  For example, to calculate `1717 mod 2`:

- Take `1717 / 2`.  The answer is 858.5
- Now take 858 and multiply it by the mod (`2`) to get `1716`
- Finally, subtract the original number (`1717`) minus the number you got from the previous step (`1716`) -- `1717-1716=1`.

So `1717 mod 2` is `1`.

To sum this up all you have to do is multiply the numbers before the decimal point with the mod then subtract it from the original number.

Answer (score 5):

type normal division first and then type shift + S->d

Comment: Works similar to the top answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[image: mod formula]
Note: Math error means a mod m = 0

Answer (score 3):

It all falls back to the definition of modulus: It is the remainder, for example, 7 mod 3 = 1.
This because 7 = 3(2) + 1, in which 1 is the remainder.

To do this process on a simple calculator do the following:
Take the dividend (7) and divide by the divisor (3), note the answer and discard all the decimals -> example 7/3 = 2.3333333, only worry about the 2. Now multiply this number by the divisor (3) and subtract the resulting number from the original dividend.

so 2*3 = 6, and 7 - 6 = 1, thus 1 is 7mod3

Comment: You method is correct and obvious, but impractical for most conditions where you would even need a calculator in the first place. In an exam for discrete math say, if you are trying to figure out congruence of very very large exponents then this method is directly impossible, and indirectly much too slow – you usually have to do a bit of RSA encrypt/decrypt in the exam by hand and without a built-in mod functionality it takes up too much time. Even our lecturers tell us this. Not a criticism of your answer, just worth pointing out it's practical limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate `x/y` (your actual numbers here), and press <kbd>a b/c</kbd> key, which is 3rd one below <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

Simply just divide the numbers, it gives yuh the decimal format and even the numerical format. using S<->D

For example: 11/3 gives you 3.666667 and 3 2/3 (Swap using S<->D).
Here the '2' from 2/3 is your mod value.

Similarly 18/6 gives you 14.833333 and 14 5/6 (Swap using S<->D).
Here the '5' from 5/6 is your mod value.