# Modulus in Casio fx991es

Tags: math, calculator

I recently found a way here on stackoverflow to calculate modulus using the fx991es. It must be configured to use radiants in order to make this work.

```
Pol(-Rec(1/(2π) , 2π×A/B), Y)(π - Y)B
```

[How to calculate a Mod b in Casio fx-991ES calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419981/how-to-calculate-a-mod-b-in-casio-fx-991es-calculator)

However I do not really understand how this works. I see that its some math-hack using polar coordinates and stuff. But why does this actually work?

Comment: Yes, this is because Rec writes `1/(2π) * sin(2π*A/B)` to `Y` and thus the value is ignored. So the `Y` component calculated by `Rec` is the second `Pol` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about this calculator specifically. But intuitively, using angles should be because they naturally are modulo 2π.
But first, we need to understand what the functions do.

- **Pol** takes 2 arguments that are Cartesian coordinates of a point (X,Y), and stores in these variables the polar coordinates : X receives the radius r, and Y the angle.
- **Rec** takes 2 arguments that are polar coordinates of a point (r,angle), and stores in these variables the Cartesian coordinates : r receives the X, and the angle receives Y.

Both these functions return the first argument if used inside an expression, i.e. Pol returns the radius r, and Rec returns X. It also says that Pol returns the angle in the angle unit defined as default in the calculator, and that it is expressed in the range `[-π,+π[`

Let us now resolve your expression according to the order of priorities in the calculator

### Rec

`Rec(1/(2π) , 2π×A/B)` returns the X coordinate of a point at a distance 1/2π from the center, and with an angle 2πA/B, which will be taken modulo 2π, effectively taking (A/B modulo 1) * 2π.

You say that Rec overwrites Y with the second coordinate -- I trust you on that, since I don't have the calculator myself and can't seem to find an emulator.

So the expression is `Pol(-X, Y)(π - Y)B`

### Pol

We now have Pol(-X,Y). Flipping the sign of X has no effect on the radius, in polar coordinates, but it changes the angle from a value A to π-A.

So we now get in the Y variable the modified the angle, thus π-2πA/B reduced in `[-π,+π[` modulo 2π. And Pol returns the radius, thus 1/(2π).

The formula is now `1/(2π)(π-Y)B`.

### Tying up loose ends

π-Y gives us now the angle shifted in [0,2π[, and dividing it by 2π yields simply `A/B modulo 1`. Multiplying by B gives then A modulo B.

#### TL;DR

Going to/from polar coordinates gives a free modulo 2π calculation, applied to A/B to get its fractional part, and the π-Y trick done twice (one written like that, the other by doing -X) is because the angle is not directly given in a range `[0,2π[`, but rather `[-π,+π[`.